# Will string concat case performant issue in PHP?

Tags: php, templates

I see some code like this in  PHP

```
public function fetch()
{
    $xml = '';
    $xml .= '<' . '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?' . '>' . "\n";
    $xml .= '<rss version="2.0">';
    $xml .= '<channel>';
    $xml .= '<title>TEST</title>';
    $xml .= '<description>TEST</description>';
    foreach ($this->items as $item)
    {
        $xml .= '<item>';
        $xml .= '<title>' . $item['title'] . '</title>';
        $xml .= '<description>' . $item['body'] . '</description>';
        $xml .= '</item>';
    }
    $xml .= '</channel>';
    $xml .= '</rss>';
    return $xml;
}
```

The code use a lots of stings concat (.=), do you think it is not a good way to do it ?
It look like will case unnecessary memory usage for me.

Those code was a part of "VIEW' of MCV, the function has already get the processed data in a array of "items". And the function is going to make the render.

Will you agree instead of

```
echo $this->fetch();
```

using a template file is better ? like this :

```
include('template.php');
```

and then in template.php :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>TEST</title>
<description>TEST</description>
    <?
    foreach ($this->items as $item){
        echo '<item>';
        echo '<title>' . $item['title'] . '</title>';
        echo '<description>' . $item['body'] . '</description>';
        echo '</item>';
    }
    ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I think the second approach would be better. Do you agree? or any other comment ?

Edit :

A user point out that using a template has it's lack too. So, when will you using the the template and when will not ? (those tutorials just always tell me i can use template anyways, i got a little confuse.)

Comment: You're building it all up as a large string in PHP memory when you concatenate, that can be a serious memory issue.... I'd suggest that you switch to using [XMLWriter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker I also prefer XMLWriter because it handles encoding and makes it simpler to produce a correct xml doc ... but I doubt memory usage would be less because it still has to store strings for all key value pairs. I think op is focusing on the wrong thing. Performance isn't an issue with concat, building a correct xml doc is.

Comment: that XML is just a random example I found in some tutorial. I like to discuss about between string building and echo function. may be even in not only XML.

Answer (score 0):

Using a template is not necessarily better since it is an I/O operation (and I/O operation are often costly).
The concatenation in comparison is several times more performant. You could either remove the unnecessary concatenations (like the '<' . '?xml' part) or use HEREDOC / NOWDOC (http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php).

At the end of the day, it's mostly up to the developper's choice as long as the application is not purely performance-driven.

EDIT: as stated in comments, using an XML reader / writer class would prove more robust and increase maintainability.

Comment: Can you tell me more about what is I/O operation ?
Is it about the include() function ? If yes, what about put those code into same php file ?

Comment: I/O means Input/Output. It basically is an operation performed on a medium like a disk, a network card, ... these operations generally use a "slow" hardware device and are thus to be avoided when possible. An example would be that reading files on a disk should not be done when the required data is / can be stored in memory.

In your case calling "include" would force PHP to open a file and read from it which is slower than simply performing a concatenation on two small-sized variables.

But again, this difference is noticeable only under heavy loads...